# This program gives either an error, or does not give the last letter, how should I fix it?

Tags: java, for-loop, substring

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Assignment4 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type the message to be shortened");
    String msg = scan.nextLine();
    msg = msg.toLowerCase();
    String alg1 = "";
    int vowelC = 0;
    int repeatC = 0;
    System.out.println("Algorithm 1");
    for (int i = 0; i<msg.length();i++){
      if(msg.substring(i-1,i).equals(" ")){
        alg1+=msg.substring(i,i+1);
      }
      else{
        if (msg.substring(i,i+1).equals("a") || msg.substring(i,i+1).equals("e") || msg.substring(i,i+1).equals("i") || msg.substring(i,i+1).equals("o") || msg.substring(i,i+1).equals("i")){
            vowelC++;
        }
        else if (msg.substring(i,i+1).equals(msg.substring(i-1,i))){
          repeatC++;
      }
        else{
        alg1+=msg.substring(i,i+1);
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.print(alg1);
    
  }
}
```

This results in a index out of range, -1. I understand why this is,that is not the issue, but when I tweak it by having the control of the for loop be i<msg.length()-1, it works but does not print the last letter. I also tried changing i to start at 1, but that cut off the first letter. Just not sure how to get the whole message with no error. Thanks!

Comment: Not your issue, but you code will be much more readable if you do all the substring stuff once = e.g. `prevChar = substring(...); nextChar = substring(...);`

Comment: Not sure why I didn't do that... that would get rid of that massive if chunk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the program trying to achieve?

Your for loop is correct, you should have `i = 0; i < length; i++`

Saying length-1 will stop one character short, as you noticed. For the substring calls, when you are using `i-1` and `ì+1` to refer to parts of the string, you should use if statements to check for the edge cases, when i=0 and when i=length, because both of those will result in out of range (e.g. results in attempts at accessing string[-1] and string[length], either of which don't exist).

Or put the substring logic inside a try...catch and carry on through the out of range exception when `err instanceOf OutOfRangeException`

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, so your saying I should put everything in an if (i!=0)? Or where would I insert that, into the preexisting if?

Comment: In each if statement, and the else if blocks, you either want to add && i!==0 and/or && i!==length - might be handy to put the string length in a local variable before the for loop for readability (cant remember if .length is a property or a method)

Not sure how that will affect your logic though, may need to refactor. Might still end up with missing out a character - I'd recommend making it more readable by first assigning the characters to local variables before beginning the if..else if...block, as suggested by @John3136, so you will then just need to say if(prevChar == nextChar)

Comment: Alright, I have fixed it, as well as making at least a bit more readable, thanks for help from everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to decipher what the output should be, try iterating through each of the characters...:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the message to be shortened");
        String msg = scan.nextLine();
        msg = msg.toLowerCase();
        String alg1 = "";
        int vowelC = 0;
        int repeatC = 0;

        System.out.println("Algorithm 1");

        char lastChar = '\n';

        for (int i = 0; i<msg.length();i++){
            char thisChar = msg.charAt(i);

            switch (thisChar) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                vowelC++;
                break;
            default:
                if(thisChar != lastChar) {
                    alg1 += thisChar;
                } else {
                    repeatC++;
                }
                break;
            }

            lastChar = thisChar;
        }

        System.out.println(alg1);

        System.out.println("Number of vowels: " + vowelC);
        System.out.println("Number of repeats: " + repeatC);
    }
}
```

Giving the output of

```
Type the message to be shortened
This is the message to be shortened
Algorithm 1
ths s th msg t b shrtnd
Number of vowels: 11
Number of repeats: 1
```